# Why the order of classes matters in angular 2 component?

Tags: angular

I'm following angular2 official tutorial and about to make '2.The Hero Editor'.
In app.component.ts file, I have two class, Hero and AppComponent.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

Because AppComponent has member type of 'Hero' class, I thought Hero must declared before the AppComponent.
But, then the weird error message was appear like below.

```
EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on AppComponent
```

And when I moved Hero class to next of AppComponent, it works... and I don't know why.
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also classes are not hoisted. If you use a class name for example `@Component({selector: 'a', directives: [B]}) class A{} @Component({selector: 'b'}) class B{}` this won't work because `B` is not yet known in `directives` because it is only declared further below. This would require `directives: [forwardRef(() => B)]`. That's just related to the title of your question. @sasxa already provided the actual answer to your error message.

Comment: Yes. now I know the sequence of class is important. Thank you for additional information!

Answer (score 1):

Decorators (`@Component` for example) work on the objects that are right after them. Your code should be:

```
@Component({...})
class Hero {}

@Component({...})
class AppComponent {}
```

If you look at the [JavaScript](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) example:

```
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
    })
    .Class({
    });
```

you can see why...

Also, if you're write multiple classes in single file, order matters. JavaScript is executed sequentially, if you ask for something that's not yet defined, you'll get an error.

Comment: Yes. I use multiple classes in single file. but I can't still understand why my code is wrong...Like you said, class 'Hero' defined just right before class AppComponent.

Comment: Sasxa's first statement is crystal clear: Decorators (@Component) will be tied with the first class right after them (in your code: Hero). So you are making Hero a component, and AppComponent therefore is just a normal class. You cannot use normal class as Component and that's why the error.

Comment: Ahhh... everything is clear now. I overlooked Sasxa's first statement.. my fault. Thanks a lot!