# How do you submit a new object to an array via multiple inputs angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Hoping for some help on a more complex example that expands on the examples in angular's [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html)

Rather than submitting a single string each time, how would you submit multiple values like in the following example e.g.:

```
          export class LittleTourComponent {
               heroes = [ {
                            'name':'Hulk',
                            'power':'strength'
                        },{
                            'name':'Bulk',
                            'power':'appetite'
                        }];
```

I presume a new 'entry' made up of the submitted values should be pushed to the heroes array something like this:

```
addHero(newHero) {
        if (newHero) {

          var entry = {
            'name': newHero.name, 
            'power': newHero.power
            };

          this.heroes.push(entry);
        }
    }
```

But what would be required in the template? Would you still use `keyup.enter` in this case?:

template:

```
<label>name</label
// how should the inputs be filled out in this scenario?
<input >
<label>power</label>
<input >

<button (click)=addHero(newHero)>Add</button>

 <ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <li>name:{{hero.name}}</li>
  <li>power:{{hero.power}}</li>
</ul>
```

example also on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zywaBtGeE6GghBED6WoH?p=preview)

Any help appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and do this in your ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

class Hero {
    name: string;
    power: string;
}
export class LittleTourComponent {

    newHero: Hero;

    constructor() {
        this.newHero = new Hero();
    }

    heroes = [{
        'name': 'Hulk',
        'power': 'strength'
    }, {
            'name': 'Bulk',
            'power': 'appetite'
        }];

    addHero() {
        if (this.newHero) {

            var entry = {
                'name': this.newHero.name,
                'power': this.newHero.power
            };

            this.heroes.push(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

...and this in your html

```
<label>name</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="newHero.name">
<label >power</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="newHero.power">

<button (click)=addHero()>Add</button>

<ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <li>name:{{hero.name}}</li>
    <li>power:{{hero.power}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Hammerschlag. I had thought that like in the original [little tour](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html) example the addHero function would require an argument that would pass the input values to the array. I created new [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFA3U3wMfnbJLo2aGJld?p=preview) based on your feedback. added the class declaration for hero and each variable is now referenced in the two way binding on the input but unfortunately still can't seem to get the solution to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is now? The solution above should work as I tried it out and it worked OK.

Comment: I figured out the issue I was having. I just needed to move the Hero class to be declared after the LittleTourComponent. I believe that’s because decorators work on the objects that come right after them as highlighted [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871626/why-the-order-of-classes-matters-in-angular-2-component). So I have accepted your answer now (with the added note that I believe the ordering of the class decoration relative to the decorators should be taken into account. Thanks again for your help Hammerschlag.

Answer (score 1):

your click listener is calling what it thinks is a reference to an element in the DOM which u havent defined nor would take paramaters. Trying putting quotes around that callback

```
<label>name</label
    // how should the inputs be filled out in this scenario?
    <input >
    <label>power</label>
    <input >
    <button (click)="addHero(newHero)">Add</button>

     <ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <li>name:{{hero.name}}</li>
      <li>power:{{hero.power}}</li>
    </ul>
```

after further review, i notice ur referencing newHero in the little-tour component which does not exist in that components scope. Also, uve bound correctly to your inputs but i dont believe .value is the correct property to return the input... try

```
 [(ngModel)]="input1"
```

in your class declaration ad

```
input1: String;
```

and then using that variable.

I didnt notice until right now that you arent importing your directive

```
import { Component }           from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

since u are calling

```
<little-tour></little-tour>
```

in your app.component.html then this should be your app component

```
import { Component }           from '@angular/core';
import {LittleTourComponent} from 'path-to-little-tour'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives: [LittleTourComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: thanks mark. I updated the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFA3U3wMfnbJLo2aGJld?p=preview) with the revised click listener and added the newHero constructor based on Hammerschlag’s feedback so I think newHero should now exist in the components scope. Using name/power now rather than .value. Do the quotes around a callback mean it’s no longer looking to reference a DOM element? thanks.

Comment: so about the callbacks. In angular2 if you are referencing something outside of quotation marks inline, it assumes that you have bound that name to a DOM element. such as <input #boundname type="text"> . By adding quotation marks u are now representing javascript from ur handler. You can use instantiated component scope variables or a function call. if you want to use a string, you must use single quotes inside of double quotes but its a common confusion

to be clear, at no point should u have this code

(click)=anything without quotes

Comment: OH, i see a much larger problem though. You are calling <little-tour></little-tour> but your app component has no clue what that is until you import it.